# What does mean : "a.s. convergence doesn't come from a metric"?

Tags: probability

In the Durrett : Probability theory and example, (4th edition), remark page 65 it says : Since there are sequence of r.v. that converge in probability but not a.s., it follow from theorem 2.3.3 that a.s. convergence does not come from a metric or even from a topology.

I'm not really sure to really understand what it mean. Could someone give explanation ? For information : theorem 2.3.3 say

> Let $y_n$ a sequence of a topological space. If every subsequence $y_{m(n)}$ has a further subsequence $y_{m(n_k)}$ that converge to $y$, then $y_n\to y$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ converges in probability to $X$ but not almost surely. Take any subsequence $\{X_{n_k}\}$. Since this sequence converges in probability it has a subsequence $\{X_{n_{k_j}}\}$  which converges almost surely. Application of Theorem 2.3.3 shows that $\{X_n\}$ must converge almost surely, but it doesn't.